# Jquery добавить данные в объект используя each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как, при помощи функции each добавить новые значения в объект?

Такой код просто перезаписывает каждый раз значение

```
var chatObj = {}

$('.class').each(function(){
  chatObj[$(this).index()] = {
    'title1': data1,
    'title2' : data2
  }
})
```

На выходе, после каждой итерации должно получиться так:

```
chatObj = {
  0: {
    title1: 'val-1',
    title2: 'val-2'
  },
  1: {
    title1: 'val-1',
    title2: 'val-2'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в незнании:

```
$('.class').each(function(index){ //add index
  chatObj[index] = { // get index
    'title1': data1,
    'title2' : data2
  }
})
```